# Trabajar con ubicación en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando una página en la que quiero añadir cosas cercanas, y que se me muestren en orden a partir de mi dirección y de la cercanía que tengo con ellas.

La idea es poner un `input` en el que al introducir las primeras palabras de mi calle, se me `autocomplete` con un sugerido que yo pueda elegir. O si no, darle simplemente a un `click` y que detecte la ubicación.

No sé si esto se puede hacer con `php` o tengo que implementar otro lenguaje, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, Sara, bienvenida a esta comunidad, te invito a que consigas tu primera medalla haciendo el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revises bien la guía de ayudar de [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante fácil, solo necesitas tener registradas las coordenadas y aplicar la fórmulas de Vincenty.

Por ejemplo, para tu posición (Lat: 4.6665578 | Long: -74.0524521)

```
SELECT id, nombre, (6371 * ACOS( 
                                SIN(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(4.6665578)) 
                                + COS(RADIANS(lng - -74.0524521)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) 
                                * COS(RADIANS(4.6665578))
                                )
                   ) AS distance
FROM direcciones
HAVING distance < 1 /* 1 KM  a la redonda */
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

[Post completo con mas explicaciones detalladas](http://www.michael-pratt.com/blog/7/Encontrar-Lugares-cercanos-con-MySQL-y-PHP/)

Answer (score 2):

Con PHP dudo que se pueda realizar algo así o seria algo rebuscado, lo mejor seria que utilizaras javascript.

En lo personal e utilizado bastante la API de **Google** y funcionaria perfecto para lo que comentas. La verdad no es tan complicado y cuenta con mucha documentación solamente es estudiarle un poco e investigar respecto a la API.

El único detalle es que desde el año pasado ya cobran por el uso de la API pero te dan un saldo a favor cada mes (por lo que tengo entendido) y si superas ese saldo ya te cobran dependiendo de las peticiones que realices a la API.

[API de Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?hl=es)